# Reducing/simplyfing polyhedrons

Tags: algorithm, matlab, convex-hull

I am looking for an algorithm that can reduce/simplify polyhedrons - reduce the number of its vertices while preserving the shape of the object. I have a set of points in 3D that represent a convex hull of an object and I would like to create a polyhedron that still contains within it all the other points, but is simpler. If there is some implementation in Matlab that would be great!

Thank you.

Comment: I have found a function in matlab reducepatch, that does something like that, but only in GUI as far as I understood.

Comment: Your goal is very unclear. Please post an example of your problem and the results you hope to achieve.

Comment: I have found an example online - http://www.digitalrune.com/Support/Blog/tabid/719/EntryId/46/Convex-Hull-Creation-and-Simplification.aspx
What I want to accomplish is the reduction of the number of vertices needed to represent the object (rabbit in this case) while preserving its shape, done in matlab.